# Does anyone know a good XeTeX tutorial?

Tags: xetex, documentation

I want to use XeTeX so that I can use a particular font, but I'm not quite sure about the documentation/commands in specifying this font in XeTeX. Can anyone point me to a good how-to tutorial on XeTeX?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're planning on using XeLaTeX, and already know LaTeX, the [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) documentation contains just about everything you need to know additionally.

Comment: Does the fontspec include ttf? I saw that supports AAT and otf.

Comment: Yes it supports ttf.

Answer (score 13):

As for good reference, there is the XeTeX manual itself (from CTAN, but see `texdoc xetex`) and this draft textbook: [The XETEX Companion. TEX meets OpenType and Unicode](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/lgc2/xetexmain.pdf), by Michel Goossens. The [XeTeX webpage](http://www.tug.org/xetex/) also includes some useful link.

Handling fonts with XeTeX has already been extensively discussed on this site; I would suggest to look for related tags.